# passing bulk array values to codebehind(cs) using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, arrays, ajax

I have to pass bulk array values to code behind (cs) using ajax i had researched a lot and used this code but it didnot worked for me below is the code that i used what i need is i need to pass bulk array values in code behind(cs) using ajax

JS

```
        <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function foo() {
            var values = ["1,", "2", "3"];

            // Make the ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Done", // the method we are calling
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ arr: values }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Yay! It worked!');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('Oh no :(');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return foo();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace PassingValueFromJavascriptToCs
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static void done(string[] ids)
        {
            String[] a = ids;
            // Do whatever processing you want
            // However, you cannot access server controls
            // in a static web method.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the button for aspx is sending your aspx form to a postback so that you would need to change the aspx like this

```
<script>
    function foo() {
        var values = ["1,", "2", "3"];

        // Make the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/Done", // the method we are calling
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ arr: values }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Yay! It worked!');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Oh no :(');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return foo();" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

The reason the foo method returns false that you dont want to make your button start a postback. I also added another property UseSubmitBehavior="false" to guarantee it.

The scripts section i changed the values object to a real array and then when sending data , i converted it to json with values object inside.  This code will work in your example just fine

**Edit** : For the working version on my tests

The aspx page (trimmed details to the master page)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script>
        function test() {
            var values = ["1,", "2", "3"];

            // Make the ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/test", // the method we are calling
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ arr: values }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    alert('Yay! It worked!');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('Oh no :(');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return test();" runat="server" Text="Deneme" />

</asp:Content>
```

The RouteConfig and original method

```
 public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void test(string[] arr)
    {

    }
```

Comment: is the page still refreshing?

Comment: OnClientClick="return foo();"  it should be like this i edited this later maybe you have missed it and also you need to change your RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method 
            //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
this line should be commented out in that method

if  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method  is the problem , you should have a "yay it worked" alert but not hitting your expected method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116505/discussion-between-volkan-seckin-akbayir-and-kavitha-vemula).

Comment: if you just come to discussion chat i can help better   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116505/discussion-between-volkan-seckin-akbayir-and-kavitha-vemula

Comment: sent it without dependant assemblies (too much file size) only code

Comment: can anyone please help me out i am not able to pass bulk array values to codebehind using the above code

Answer (score 0):

Well at least one issue is your url is "Default.aspx/Done" but the method appears to be on WebForm3.aspx/Done.
What actually happens with your code? Does it error?